how to get variation_id of the selected variable
I made a custom add-to-cart for WordPress, but it doesn't work for variable products, for example, for a product with a red color and 128GB memory, a separate ID is considered, how can I get that ID?
I get the variables with the following codes and the user chooses
<?php $variations = $product->get_variation_attributes();
                    $available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();
                   
                    ?>
                    <?php foreach ($variations as $key => $value): ?>
                        <div class="d-flex">
                            <div class="ms-2">
                                <span><?php echo $key; ?></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="d-flex">
                                <?php foreach ($value as $var): ?>

                                    <div class="button-group">
                                        <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $key ?>" value="<?php echo $var; ?>" id="<?php echo $var; ?>">
                                        <label class="artheme_var_id" name="<?php echo $key ?>" id="<?php echo $var; ?>" for="<?php echo $var; ?>"><?php echo $var; ?></label>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endforeach;  ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>

I need help to find the ID of the selected variable
This information is returned
                        array(8) {
  [0]=>
  array(24) {
    ["attributes"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["attribute_pa_color"]=>
      string(4) "blue"
      ["attribute_pa_storage"]=>
      string(5) "128gb"
    }
    ["availability_html"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["backorders_allowed"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["dimensions"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["length"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["width"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["height"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
    ["dimensions_html"]=>
    string(14) "نامعلوم"
    ["display_price"]=>
    float(147741)
    ["display_regular_price"]=>
    float(147741)
    ["image"]=>
    array(18) {
      ["title"]=>
      string(28) "Best-Mibro-A2-Accessories-14"
      ["caption"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["url"]=>
      string(76) "http://haji.test/wp-content/uploads/2024/05/Best-Mibro-A2-Accessories-14.jpg"
      ["alt"]=>
      string(28) "Best-Mibro-A2-Accessories-14"
      ["src"]=>
      string(84) "http://haji.test/wp-content/uploads/2024/05/Best-Mibro-A2-Accessories-14-600x380.jpg"
      ["srcset"]=>
      string(448) "http://haji.test/wp-content/uploads/2024/05/Best-Mibro-A2-Accessories-14-600x380.jpg 600w, http://haji.test/wp-content/uploads/2024/05/Best-Mibro-A2-Accessories-14-300x190.jpg 300w, http://haji.test/wp-content/uploads/2024/05/Best-Mibro-A2-Accessories-14-1024x649.jpg 1024w, http://haji.test/wp-content/uploads/2024/05/Best-Mibro-A2-Accessories-14-768x486.jpg 768w, http://haji.test/wp-content/uploads/2024/05/Best-Mibro-A2-Accessories-14.jpg 1200w"
      ["sizes"]=>
      string(31) "(max-width: 600px) 100vw, 600px"
      ["full_src"]=>
      string(76) "http://haji.test/wp-content/uploads/2024/05/Best-Mibro-A2-Accessories-14.jpg"
      ["full_src_w"]=>
      int(1200)
      ["full_src_h"]=>
      int(760)
      ["gallery_thumbnail_src"]=>
      string(84) "http://haji.test/wp-content/uploads/2024/05/Best-Mibro-A2-Accessories-14-100x100.jpg"
      ["gallery_thumbnail_src_w"]=>
      int(100)
      ["gallery_thumbnail_src_h"]=>
      int(100)
      ["thumb_src"]=>
      string(84) "http://haji.test/wp-content/uploads/2024/05/Best- 
    Mibro-A2-Accessories-14-300x300.jpg"
      ["thumb_src_w"]=>
      int(300)
      ["thumb_src_h"]=>
      int(300)
      ["src_w"]=>
      int(600)
      ["src_h"]=>
      int(380)
    }
    ["image_id"]=>
    int(76)
    ["is_downloadable"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["is_in_stock"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["is_purchasable"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["is_sold_individually"]=>
    string(2) "no"
    ["is_virtual"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["max_qty"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["min_qty"]=>
    int(1)
    ["price_html"]=>
    string(198) "<span class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price- 
    amount amount"><bdi>147.741&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price- 
     currencySymbol">&#x062A;&#x0648;&#x0645;&#x0627;&#x0646;</span> 
    </bdi></span></span>"
    ["sku"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["variation_description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["variation_id"]=>
    int(750)
    ["variation_is_active"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["variation_is_visible"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["weight"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["weight_html"]=>
     string(14) "نامعلوم"
      }
      [1]=>
     array(24) {
     ["attributes"]=>
     array(2) {
      ["attribute_pa_color"]=>
      string(4) "blue"
      ["attribute_pa_storage"]=>
      string(5) "256gb"
    }
    ["availability_html"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["backorders_allowed"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["dimensions"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["length"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["width"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["height"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
    ["dimensions_html"]=>
    string(14) "نامعلوم"
    ["display_price"]=>
    float(852025)
    ["display_regular_price"]=>
    float(852025)
    ["image"]=>
    array(18) {
      ["title"]=>
      string(28) "Best-Mibro-A2-Accessories-14"
      ["caption"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["url"]=>
      string(76) "http://haji.test/wp-content/uploads/2024/05/Best-Mibro-A2-Accessories-14.jpg"
      ["alt"]=>
      string(28) "Best-Mibro-A2-Accessories-14"
      ["src"]=>
      string(84) "http://haji.test/wp-content/uploads/2024/05/Best-Mibro-A2-Accessories-14-600x380.jpg"
      ["srcset"]=>
      string(448) "http://haji.test/wp-content/uploads/2024/05/Best-Mibro-A2-Accessories-14-600x380.jpg 600w, http://haji.test/wp-content/uploads/2024/05/Best-Mibro-A2-Accessories-14-300x190.jpg 300w, http://haji.test/wp-content/uploads/2024/05/Best-Mibro-A2-Accessories-14-1024x649.jpg 1024w, http://haji.test/wp-content/uploads/2024/05/Best-Mibro-A2-Accessories-14-768x486.jpg 768w, http://haji.test/wp-content/uploads/2024/05/Best-Mibro-A2-Accessories-14.jpg 1200w"
      ["sizes"]=>
      string(31) "(max-width: 600px) 100vw, 600px"
      ["full_src"]=>
      string(76) "http://haji.test/wp-content/uploads/2024/05/Best-Mibro-A2-Accessories-14.jpg"
      ["full_src_w"]=>
      int(1200)
      ["full_src_h"]=>
      int(760)
      ["gallery_thumbnail_src"]=>
      string(84) "http://haji.test/wp-content/uploads/2024/05/Best-Mibro-A2-Accessories-14-100x100.jpg"
      ["gallery_thumbnail_src_w"]=>
      int(100)
      ["gallery_thumbnail_src_h"]=>
      int(100)
      ["thumb_src"]=>
      string(84) "http://haji.test/wp-content/uploads/2024/05/Best-Mibro-A2-Accessories-14-300x300.jpg"
      ["thumb_src_w"]=>
      int(300)
      ["thumb_src_h"]=>
      int(300)
      ["src_w"]=>
      int(600)
      ["src_h"]=>
      int(380)
    }
    ["image_id"]=>
    int(76)
    ["is_downloadable"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["is_in_stock"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["is_purchasable"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["is_sold_individually"]=>
    string(2) "no"
    ["is_virtual"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["max_qty"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["min_qty"]=>
    int(1)
    ["price_html"]=>
    string(198) "<span class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>852.025&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#x062A;&#x0648;&#x0645;&#x0627;&#x0646;</span></bdi></span></span>"
    ["sku"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["variation_description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["variation_id"]=>
    int(751)
    ["variation_is_active"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["variation_is_visible"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["weight"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["weight_html"]=>
    string(14) "نامعلوم"
  }


Could you add the result of $available_variations because it should contains the id of each variant

There is a lot of information and I don't know how to find the ID by choosing "red" and "128gb".

Not sure what you're missing exactly, but i'll put here a JS script that runs on frontend and updates the selected variation to the "Add To Cart" button, making it to function correctly. Hope it Helps.
 $('body').on('check_variations', function () {
    const $form = $('.variations_form');
    const $price = $form.find('.single_variation_wrap .single_variation');
    const $variationIdInput = $form.find('input[name="variation_id"]');
    const $quantityInput = $form.find('input[name="quantity"]');

    const variationsData = $form.data('product_variations');
    const selectedTerms = $form.find('.variations select').map((idx, attr) => {
        const attrObj = {};
        attrObj[attr.name] = $(attr).val();
        return attrObj;
    }).toArray();
    const matchedVariation = variationsData.find(variation => {
        return selectedTerms.every(term => {
            const key = Object.keys(term)[0];
            return variation.attributes[key] == term[key];
        });
    });
    if (!matchedVariation) return;
    const variationId = matchedVariation.variation_id;
    const priceHtml = matchedVariation.price_html;
    const maxQuantity = matchedVariation.max_qty;
    $price.html(priceHtml);
    $variationIdInput.val(variationId);
    $quantityInput.attr('max', maxQuantity);
    if($quantityInput.val() > maxQuantity){
        $quantityInput.val(maxQuantity);
    }
});

